# Is it possible to create a mobile sync for contacts with cordova

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I've been tasked to create an app that would allow users to auto-sync their mobile contacts with an online list of contacts that periodically updates.

I'm using Ionic / Cordova for the application.

Has anyone had success / failure doing this with Cordova?

Comment: Why should it not be possible? Use the [contact plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-contacts) to find out if a contact exists and create contacts if needed. To sync your contacts with a online list a web service might work.